# How do I prevent the main window from losing focus?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, wpf-controls

How do I prevent the main window (where I write something in the textbox) from losing focus?

The application has a couple of pop-up windows that sometimes show up and it prevents me from continuing to write text in the main window (and I have to click back to it).

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: if u want to have the mainwindow alltime in focus.. u cant do any other stuff, cuz if u write sth in a textbox, ur textbox get the focus

Comment: ok, otherwise.. i want to other windows don't have focus if they appear, so I can continue writing in the main window

Comment: you could try attaching a handler to the Window.deactivated event that put focus back on your window/textbox, but you would have to open your pop ups on a separate thread or as @Ganeshkumar suggests a modeless window

Answer (score 0):

You have to create those popup windows as modeless window.

[Refer microsoft sample here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Modeless-Window-in-WPF-492cb24f)